# C++においてif else文の条件分岐が上手くいかない

Tags: c++

[AtCoderの問題](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc070/tasks/abc070_b) に取り組んでいて自分でコードを書いたところ上手くいかないので質問させて頂きます。

**コード**

```
#include  '<'iostream'>'
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int A, B, C, D;

    cin >> A >> B >> C >> D;
    if (C <= A) {
        if (D <= A) cout << 0 << endl;
        else if (A < D < B) cout << D - A << endl;
        else if(D >= B)     cout << B - A << endl;
    }
    else if (A < C < B) {
        if (D <= B) cout << D - C << endl;
        else if(D >=B)  cout << B - C << endl;
    }
    else 
        cout << 0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Cのとる値で場合分けをしているのですが、最後の条件分岐の C >=Bの場合が上手く動作しません。

例)
入力を5,10,20,40とした場合出力が0になる想定なのですが、-10と出力されてしまいます。
コードが間違っているのでしょうか。教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `else if (A < C < B) {`

とあなたは書いていますが、真の意図は `A < C && C < B` でしょうか？

[c](/questions/tagged/c) / [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) においては、言語仕様がそう定めている都合上 `A < C < B` と書いても範囲比較にはなりません。仕様が定めている処理は下記のようになります

- `A < C` の比較を行い、偽なら `false` `0` 真なら `true` `1` を得ます
- 先の比較結果を使って `0 または 1 < B` の比較を行います

そのため入力として `B` に `10` を与えると `A < C < B` は常に真となります（`A` と `C` に何を与えても比較結果は `0` または `1` なので）。
もう一か所ありますよね

Comment: 言語仕様について詳しく説明して頂きありがとうございます。理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

```
if (A < D < B)
```

という書き方ではなく

```
if ( A < D && D < B )
```

と書いてください。`A < D < B`と書きたくなる気持ちは分かりますが、この式は文法的には正しくてコンパイルを通ってしまいますが、求めている判定とは違う結果を返します。

Comment: 解決することができました。ありがとうございます！